# SQL: Show only the Percentile

Tags: sql

I have this working query

```
SELECT MIN([DealerCode])   
    ,[201309]   
    ,RowNum = Row_Number() OVER(Order By [201309])   
    ,Rnk = RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [201309])   
    ,DenseRnk = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [201309])   
    ,NTile4  = NTILE(100) OVER(ORDER BY [201309])   
    ,BM = RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [201309])*0.7 

FROM [SA_Sew].[dbo].[Sew_YTD_Composite$]   
where Ratio_ID = 'fi02u' AND DealerCode like '%VW%'    
GROUP BY [201309];
```

How would I be able to get the NTile4 calculation as a field to be able to use it in the Where Field? NTile4 = 70 is benchmark and I need to only see the benchmark.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write as:

```
select * from 
(
SELECT MIN([DealerCode]) as MinDealerCode   
    ,[201309]   
    ,RowNum = Row_Number() OVER(Order By [201309])   
    ,Rnk = RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [201309])   
    ,DenseRnk = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [201309])   
    ,NTile4  = NTILE(100) OVER(ORDER BY [201309])   
    ,BM = RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [201309])*0.7 

FROM [SA_Sew].[dbo].[Sew_YTD_Composite$]   
where Ratio_ID = 'fi02u' AND DealerCode like '%VW%'    
GROUP BY [201309]
) as T
where NTile4  = 70;
```

Comment: Nearly there, but I get this error message Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake i missed to remove delimiter ; after group by . edited query please try now.

Comment: Then it gives me:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: Still an error.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 15
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'T'.

Comment: sorry again but it's mainly because i tried to write it as psuedo code .. hope this works now..